# Failover web server cluster role

Tags: high-availability, windows-server, failover, windows-server-2016, failovercluster

I want to create a failover web server using Windows Server 2016. If the first machine fails, the server should move to the second machine. However I'm not really sure which `Clustered Role` should I use.

```
Clustered Role  Role or Feature Prerequisite
DFS Namespace Server    DFS Namespaces (part of File Server role)
DHCP Server DHCP Server role
Distributed Transaction Coordinator (DTC)   None
File Server File Server role
Generic Application Not applicable
Generic Script  Not applicable
Generic Service Not applicable
Hyper-V Replica Broker  Hyper-V role
iSCSI Target Server iSCSI Target Server (part of File Server role)
iSNS Server iSNS Server Service feature
Message Queuing Message Queuing Services feature
Other Server    None
Virtual Machine Hyper-V role
WINS Server WINS Server feature
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/failover-clustering/create-failover-cluster#create-clustered-roles. PS: I want a situation with and without a database.

Comment: I think you want "Network Load Balancing" .    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/network-load-balancing    The critical detail is that this is a software solution tied to the Windows OS and makes your overall config a bit more complicated.   Typically this is done with hardware or dedicated VMs at the network level like with F5 and similar services. There are so many details involved in failover and load balancing - please talk to an experienced person about your specific scenario if this is an important production system.

Comment: @SqlSurfer I know that network load balancing distributes the load between the two machines (in my situation). Is there a way that the "backup" machine just stays idle until my server fails?

Comment: I would clarify this in your mind...  Do you want the fail over to be truly automatic or do you want it to be manually imitated. (Pre configured and warm - but not fully active without human intervention).   This fail over topic is so app specific that it would be hard to give a good answer in a QA forum.

Comment: @SqlSurfer automatic is what i want